# access root event in EB input transformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

i have an input event, for example:
`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}`

i would like to add an input transformer to output the following:

`{"task_id": "some_const_id", "payload": {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}}`

so basically id like to put the entire event as a key in the output event.

i tried to access the "root" event by using things like:

input path:

`{"payload": "$"}`

template:

`{"task_id": "some_const_id", "payload":"<payload>"}`

but `$` is not the correct way to access it. couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it,
the var name is called:

```
<aws.events.event.json>
```

template now looks like this:

```
{"task_id": "some_const_id", "payload":<aws.events.event.json>}
```